# MySQL - INSERT trigger for two columns

Tags: mysql, triggers

How to create a trigger to do a math for two columns. Below is an example.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `POBRANY` BEFORE INSERT ON `TAB1`
FOR EACH ROW SET
NEW.POBR_SUROW = (NEW.Column_1_ILO + NEW.Column_2_ILO + NEW.Column_3_ILO + NEW.Column_4_ILO + NEW.Column_5_ILO + NEW.Column_6_ILO)
AND 
NEW.SUMA_GODZIN = (NEW.LICZBA_GODZIN_PRACY * NEW.ILO_OS_B_NA_PRODUKCJI)
```

Comment: Separate set with comma not and..also terminate statement. IF you have syntax errors (and you do) publish them in full.

Comment: Convert these 2 columns to generated columns, and you do not need in a trigger at all.

Comment: @P.Salmon I don't understand where to separate with a comma.

Comment: @Akina It can tell you how to do it?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html

Comment: @Akina Thanks! Everything works fine without trigger insert/update.